# Does the server closure for ModNation Racers affect user-generated content?

Tags: mod-nation-racers-road-trip

As most of you already know, Sony closed the online servers for ModNation Racers: Road Trip for Vita, so there is no online multiplayer for it.

Does anyone know if this affects user-generated content? That is, will you still be able to download karts or maps or is it all gone for good?

Comment: If you are going to downvote, could at least explain the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are no longer to able to connect to the servers, as they have been taken down. Accessing the community content requires you to connect to the server, which is no longer in service.

That means you are unable to download or view any online content, including checking your Creator ranking. (I was trying to get level 28 for the platinum and tried to check my progress recently, so I can confirm this behavior)

Comment: So basically, there's no way to get any user-generated content

Comment: @ChuckBirkin yes.